# why does this code change the string but again revert back to original state

Tags: javascript, string, data-structures

```
function capital(b){
    let letter = b[0].toUpperCase();
    return letter + b.slice(1);
}

function correction(a){
    let place = a.indexOf('_');
    let part1 = a.slice(0, place);
    let part2 = a.slice(place+1);
    a = part1 + capital(part2);
    if (a.includes('_'))
        correction(a);
    return a;
}
```

When I call `correction("Hey_there_How_are_you")`, I see in while debugging that it becomes "HeyThereHowAreYou" but again becomes as original string itself. What could be the problem?

Comment: because string is not refefernce type. I suggest you read about `difference between value type and reference type`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the result of the call in your conditional so that it can be used again.

```js
function capital(b) {
  let letter = b[0].toUpperCase();
  return letter + b.slice(1);
}

function correction(a) {
  let place = a.indexOf('_');
  let part1 = a.slice(0, place);
  let part2 = a.slice(place + 1);
  a = part1 + capital(part2);
  if (a.includes('_')) {
    return correction(a);
  }
  return a;
}

let x = correction("Hey_there_How_are_you");
console.log(x);
```